# Which finite sets could be packed into a square?

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, plane-geometry, ordinal-numbers, packing-and-covering

This question is inspired by an interesting visualization of the finite levels of von Neumann's hierarchy on [Adam P. Goucher](https://mathoverflow.net/users/39521/adam-p-goucher)'s blog, [Complex Projective 4-Space](https://cp4space.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/von-neumann-universe/).

The problem starts with a two-dimensional visualization of the [Bourbaki notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set#Notation) $\{\}$ for the empty set as a square-shaped *wall* surrounding the space quantum of the 2D plane, a pixel, and then constructing such a representation for all other finite sets through a recursive process.

If such a 2D representation is in hand for the finite sets $a_0, \cdots, a_n$, a 2D representation for the set $b=\{a_0, \cdots, a_n\}$ could be obtained through packing $a_0, \cdots, a_n$ and adding a *wall* around them in such a way that the distance between the wall and the sets inside it as well as all gaps between neighboring sets are exactly $1$ pixel wide. The following illustration shows the representation for the first few levels of the von Neumann's hierarchy.

[image]

[image]

Of course, such a 2D representation for a finite set is not necessarily unique. Also, a distinguished phenomenon is that in some special cases, it seems the 2D representation of a finite set like $0=\{\}$ or $1=\{\{\}\}$ could be arranged in a *square-shaped* way. This gives rise to the following definition:

**Definition.** A finite set is called *square* if it has a square-shaped representation in the 2D plane.

> **Question 1.** Is there a characterization of all square finite sets?
>
> **Question 2.** Is there any square natural number or finite level of von Neumann's hierarchy except $0, 1$ and $V_0, V_1$? If yes, are there infinitely many of them?

As it seems the degree of freedom in choosing the 2D representation of a finite set drastically increases by the cardinality (but not rank) of the set, one may guess that all sufficiently large finite sets have a square 2D representation. Thus the following natural question arises:

> **Question 3.** Is there a natural number $n$ such that for any $a\in V_{\omega}$, if $|a|\geq n$ then $a$ is square?

**Remark.** Note that the degree of freedom in choosing the representation doesn't increase by changing the rank necessarily. There are finite sets of arbitrary high rank in the von Neumann's hierarchy such as $\{\{\}, \{\{\}\}\}=2, \{2\}, \{\{2\}\}, \cdots$ which have no square representation (each of them is produced by adding a wall to $2$ which is already known to have no square representation).

Comment: If you allow repetition of elements, which is usually allowed in the brace notation, then it seems to me that every hereditarily finite set will be represented by a square. Just find the right common multiples.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins (+1) I see! That sounds reasonable. However, the uniqueness of elements in such a *labyrinth*-esque representation of the finite sets adds much more beauty to the problem. I actually spent some time looking at the attractive distribution of little boxes (representing $\emptyset$) in $V_4$ diagram imagining how enjoyable it would be to have a wallpaper with the (possibly square-shape) pattern of one of my favorite finite sets/numbers on it in my room! ;-) By the way I wonder if "labyrinth" (that is a bit different structurally) a good candidate for naming this representation.

Comment: Note that there is a kind of non-uniqueness present in many of your pictures: the empty set is represented several times in many of them, and also singleton empty set. What is the reason to insist on uniqueness for the top-level elements, if you allow non-uniqueness for the hereditary structure?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins To preserve the information about the number of building blocks of the universe (i.e. $\emptyset$ or protons) that are used in the formation of different molecules (finite sets). If one assigns a unit mass $1$ to $\emptyset$ and assume that adding braces adds nothing to the total mass of the object, then different labyrinth representations of a set will have the same *mass* (as well as *hereditary structure*). Note that the mass of a finite set could be different from its cardinality. For instance, $|\{V_3\}|=1$ but its mass is equal to that of $V_3$ which is $5$.

Comment: Apart from some extraterrestrial applications of such visual representations of mathematical objects which may come in handy in possible future communications with the alien species (Seriously! They already tried it on [Voyager's golden disc](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/The_Sounds_of_Earth_Record_Cover_-_GPN-2000-001978.jpg)!), one can also imagine some terrestrial applications of the labyrinth representation in computer science, particularly when it comes to memory management. Maybe CS experts can let us know whether any similar partition on a memory disc is useful.